# Add unique ID to a session

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, database

Hello and thanks for reading this, could really use some help ;)

On my site, you play a puzzle after you entered your information and when you either complete the game before the time runs out or not your score will be posted into the gridview below.

I cant post a image but you can check the site if you want a good view about what I'm talking about [Website](http://medieproduktion.mediacollege.dk:10279/Game1/)

everything is working right now. you can play it and as you can see the time is showed. in the database that the information is stored in you every row has a unique ID.

here is my question - when someone hits "start spillet" and adds the information to the database, how can i get the unique ID that when that just been created and store it into a session so i can use it later.

(here is a row from my Database)

```
 ID    NAME      EMAIL                      COLLEGE         CLASS/TEAM      TIME
 114   Carsten   TESTUSER@mediacollege.dk   Technology  h0dt100413  54
```

Comment: `Session["id"] = the_id_from_db`. Do you need help on how to get it from the database as well?

Comment: thanks for your quick respond, what i need help with is how to get the Unique ID thats just been created when the users enters the information.

Comment: We need some more information. How do you access your database? Entity Framework, vanilla sql? Give us some concrete information

Comment: can you post your code which you use to save data in database ?

Comment: As others have correctly said how you get the id will depend on how you are writing the object to the database so we need to see that code or at least have a description of how it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public string generateID()
{
    return Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N");
}
```

using this function you will get a unique id and you can user it as session.

it will different every time